# How to make Ember sass compatible with glob match

Tags: ember.js

I would like to import scss files using glob match such as `components/*` but seems Ember-sass-cli does not support this feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ember-cli-sass` just runs `libsass` and globbing is explicit not a feature of sass. So yeah, this won't work.

If you want to import multiple files I would recommend to concat them together in a build step before `ember-cli-sass`, so sass can operate on a single file to import.

Also maybe checkout `ember-css-modules` or `ember-component-css`.